# Getting the contents of an element WITHOUT its children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mild preference in solving this in pure JS, but if the jQuery version is simpler, then jQuery is fine too. Effectively the situation is like this

```
<span id="thisone">
 The info I want
 <span id="notthisone">
  I don't want any of this nonsense
 </span>
</span>
```

I effectively want to get
`The info I want`
but not
`The info I want I don't want any of this nonsense`
and I especially don't want
`The info I want <span id="notthisone"> I don't want any of this nonsense </span>`
which is unfortunately what I am getting right now...

How would I do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

With js only:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/g4tRn/

```
var result = document.getElementById('thisone').firstChild.nodeValue;    

​alert(result);​
```

With jQuery:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/g4tRn/1

```
var result = $('#thisone').contents().first().text();  

alert(result);​
```

**Bonus:**

If there are other text nodes in the outer `<span>` that you want to get, you could do something like this:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/g4tRn/4

```
var nodes = document.getElementById('thisone').childNodes;
var result = '';

for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if(nodes[i].nodeType == 3) {       // If it is a text node,
        result += nodes[i].nodeValue;  //    add its text to the result
    }
}

alert(result);
​
```

Comment: @richardtallent - You mean like a hybrid? That's true. A little less code that way. http://jsfiddle.net/g4tRn/2/

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the first child then it's rather simple. If you are looking for the first text-only element then this code will need some modification.

```
var text = document.getElementById('thisone').firstChild.nodeValue;
alert(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var thisone = $("#thisone").clone();
thisone.children().remove();
var mytext = thisone.html();
```

Comment: `.text()` at the end, surely?

Answer (score 0):

FROM: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2011/02/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element.html

```
 $("#foo")
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text();    //get the text of element
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pure JavaScript

In this pure JavaScript example, I account for the *possibility of multiple text nodes* that could be *interleaved with other kinds of nodes*. Pass a containing `NodeList` in from calling / client code.

```
function getText (nodeList, target)
{
    var trueTarget = target - 1;
    var length = nodeList.length; // Because you may have many child nodes.

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if ((nodeList[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) && (i === trueTarget)) {
            return nodeList.childNodes[i].nodeValue;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

You might use this function to create a wrapper function that uses this one to accumulate multiple text values.

Answer (score 0):

To get a string of the child text nodes and not the element or other child nodes from a given element:

```js
function getTextNodesText(el) {
  return Array.from(el.childNodes)
    .filter((child) => child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
    .map((child) => child.textContent)
    .join("");
}
```

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/72970334/6243352. Please post the answer in one thread only.