# How to parse 'div' without name?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Using Jsoup:

```
Element movie_div = doc.select("div.movie").first();
```

I got a such HTML-code:

```html
<div class="movie"> 
    <div> 
        <div>
            <strong>Year:</strong> 2014
        </div> 
        <div>
            <strong>Country:</strong> USA
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

How can I use jsoup to extract the country and the year?

For the example html I want the extracted values to be `"2014"` and `"USA"`.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what "parse" exactly means, but if It means that you want to get/change those data you probably need to place it in <span class="somename">. Each one should have the same class. And than, using jQuery, get all ".somename" span's and do what you want

Comment: @Ludwik11: 1) No need to change the html (which may not be possible [or at least illegal], if it's loaded from a webside the OP doesn't own). Text nodes are nodes. They just can't be selected with css only. Even from javascript this is possible, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6520192/2991525 . 2) This is NOT about javascript. I don't know how you plan to use jQuery from **java** but to me it sounds like nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Element e = doc.select("div.movie").first().child(0);
List<TextNode> textNodes = e.child(0).textNodes();
String year = textNodes.get(textNodes.size()-1).text().trim();
textNodes = e.child(1).textNodes();
String country = textNodes.get(textNodes.size()-1).text().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
Element movie_div = doc.select("div.movie strong").first();
```

And to get the text value you should try;

```
movie_div.text();
```

Comment: That way I get "Year:" and "Country:", but no "2014" and "USA", cause `text()` gets the combined text of this element.

Comment: @MarkKorzhov True, you should use `.parent()` function before getting the text and then remove the strong tag's text