# jQuery replace only the text of a node, ignoring current internal nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML:

```
<label>Search:
  <input id="search-box" type="text"/>
</label>
```

If I want to change the words "Search:" to "Quick Search:", how can I select just the "Search:" text using jQuery/JS?

I have tried `html()`, `text()`, and other various jQuery methods.  My goal is to NOT have to copy the input box and then append it after.  Is it possible?

P.S.  I know I can use the `prepend()` function, but my goal here is to replace that text entirely, and I'd like to know how to do this in the future as well.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/get-text-node-of-an-element has the start of a solution for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the HTML I'd wrap the text in a `span` so that you can address it easily. However, with what you have so far you can simply iterate over all nodes in the element and change the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the  first text node (`nodeType==3`):

```js
$(function(){
    
    $("label").contents().each(function() {
        if(this.nodeType == 3){
            this.textContent = "Quick Search: ";
            return false;
        }
    })
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Search:
  <input id="search-box" type="text"/>
</label>
```

Comment: FYI: the rendered output of this answer is a little different since it will lose a whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

To do it you would need to look at the text nodes. You get them by using `contents()`. This solution below is a little overkill, but this shows you how to look for a textNode (type 3) and look to see if the text has Search in it.

```js
var textNodes = $("label")
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf("Search")>-1; 
  }).each( function() { this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("Search", "Quick Search"); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Search:
  <input id="search-box" type="text"/>
</label>
```

You can get rid of the filter and just do it all in the each and break out if you want.

```
var textNodes = $("label")  //should use a better selector
  .contents()
  .each(function() {
      if( this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf("Search")>-1 ) {   
          this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("Search", "Quick Search");
          return false; 
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with straight Javascript...no jQuery needed. You just need to access the first node in the label and change the value.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('label')[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "Quicksearch: ";
```

```html
<label>Search:
  <input id="search-box" type="text"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Clearly far superior to my own answer. I'm all for jQuery-free solutions. (N.b. nit-pickers might want you to change 'Quicksearch: ' to 'Quick Search: ')

Comment: As long as the firstChild is the text to replace it will work.

Comment: Right...if the markup changes, you'd be better off looping through and checking for the nodeType.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove all text part from label, and then insert another text

```
$('label').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();

$('label input').before('Quick Search: ');
```

---

For reusable porpose, you can extend jQuery adding a method for that.

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.replaceText = function(oldText, newText) {
        this.contents().each(function(){
            if (this.nodeType === 3) {
                this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(oldText, newText);
            }
        });
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));

$('label').replaceText('Search', 'Quick Search');
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the result but with **dataTable search id** :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
        
    $("#myTable_filter label").contents().each(function() {
        if(this.nodeType == 3){
            this.textContent = "Quick Search:";
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Col-1</th><th>Col-2</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>name 1</td><td>User-1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>name 2</td><td>User-2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>name 3</td><td>User-3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to [@jlbruno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32098352/1921385) here's a jQuery-free method that iterates over *every* `label` and case-insensitively replaces every instance of `Search` with `Quick Search` regardless of the position of the textNode.

```js
(function(){
    
    var labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');
    for (l = 0; l < labels.length; ++l){
        var label = labels[l],
            nodes = label.childNodes;
        for (n = 0; n < nodes.length; ++n){
            var node = nodes[n];
            if(node.nodeType===3 && node.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf("search")>=0){
             node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/search/i,"Quick Search");
            }
        }
    }
    
})();
```

```html
<label>Search:
  <input name="search" type="search"/>
</label>
<br />
<label>Do you like bees?
  <input name="beesPlease" type="checkbox"/>
</label>
<br />
<label>
    <textarea name="textarea">this instance of search will not be changed</textarea>
</label>
<br />
<label>Search This Mofo: 
  <input name="search-this" type="text"/>
</label>
<br />
<label>Fill me 
  <input name="search-that" type="text"/>
  with your search.
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a span tag inside the label and before the input. Give the span a id attribute and replace text inside that span with your text. It's better to prevent using html replacement for this.

Comment: That is a good idea, however this HTML is generated by a JavaScript plugin (DataTables.net), therefore I do not have control over how that is generated.

Comment: That's indeed something else. You could. But it's not the best way. Get the current html, replace parts of it and put it back.

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to put it in a separate element, you can't grab and update just the text and not the input with the way it's laid out currently.

The easiest way would be to use a span tag and then modify that like this:

```
<label id="my-label"><span>Search:</span>
  <input id="search-box" type="text"/>
</label>
```

and then use this to do modify it:

```
$('#my-label > span').text('Quicksearch:');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/orj8gkxc/

Comment: @epascarello OK, I'll wait for your answer showing how then because with my knowledge of jQuery I don't know how to do it.