# Viewing [object HTMLInputElement] - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I using javascript to extract the value from the SPAN element, then put it in a hidden form field, and then submit the data but why am I getting this result?

```
<form onsubmit="CDMFOCT()" id="CDMFOCTform">
    <div class="CDMFOCT"></div>
    <span class="CDMFOCT-span"></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="CDMFOCTtimer" id="CDMFOCTtimer" value="not yet defined"> 
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function CDMFOCT() {
    CronSaati = $('.CDMFOCT-span').html();
    $("#CDMFOCTtimer").val(CDMFOCTtimer);
    $("#CDMFOCTform").submit();
};
```

**Output:**

```
Time: [object HTMLInputElement] will...
```

Comment: @AliSeyfi I updated my question

Comment: Where is `CDMFOCTtimer` (inside the `val()`) set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript & jQuery to extract the value of span:

```
var node = $('.CDMFOCT-span')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

**Edit:** Or just simply:

```
var node = $(.CDMFOCT-span).text();
```

Read more about how to get text node of an element in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/get-text-node-of-an-element)

and now putting it in the hidden form field:

```
$("input#CDMFOCTtimer").val(node);
```

Comment: Working but all input was the same, I tried `input[type=hidden,id=CDMFOCTtimer]`  it's possible?

Comment: @Saracoglu what do you mean?

Comment: I have multiple inputs, therefore all inputs set content of `CDMFOCT-span` - Is it possible to give a direct address to the Input?

Comment: so specify which input type, for example give an id like *myInput* to the input tag and select the specified input tag by jquery like `$(input#myInput).val(node);`

Answer (score 1):

The are two problem in your code

1. `$("#CDMFOCTtimer").val(CDMFOCTtimer);` should be replaced with `$("#CDMFOCTtimer").val(CronSaati);` to give the hidden field value of your span.
2. you have set `CronSaati` as a variable. `var CronSaati = $('.CDMFOCT-span').html();`

So Try this

```js
$("#CDMFOCTform").submit(function() {
  var CronSaati = $('.CDMFOCT-span').html();
  $("#CDMFOCTtimer").val(CronSaati);

  // just for showing the html content of your span has been inserted into hidden input field
  alert($("#CDMFOCTtimer").val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="CDMFOCTform" method="post" action="">
  <div class="CDMFOCT"></div>
  <span class="CDMFOCT-span">Hello</span>
  <input type="hidden" name="CDMFOCTtimer" id="CDMFOCTtimer" value="not yet defined">
  <input type="submit" name="CDMFOCTsubmit">
</form>
```