# How to get the inner Text inside span using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nextsibling

The link is here;
http://heart.bmj.com/content/early/2016/08/10/heartjnl-2016-310003.long

I have;

```
<span class="cit-title">
    <span class="cit-series-title">Original article
        <span class="cit-sep cit-sep-after-article-series-title">:</span>
    </span>Pregnancy outcomes in patients with pulmonary arterial hypertension associated with congenital heart disease 
</span>
```

What have I done so far?

I select the `span.cit-title` but it's `innerText`

gives me;

```
"Original article: Pregnancy outcomes in patients with pulmonary arterial hypertension associated with congenital heart disease"
```

I want to get only the

```
"Pregnancy outcomes in patients with pulmonary arterial hypertension associated with congenital heart disease"`
```

part.

How can I exclude span with class `cit-series-title` and get the raw text?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/get-text-node-of-an-element. You'll find your answere there.

Comment: is that many spans really needed?

Comment: I try to parse the html. So I am not the author of the spans. :)

Answer (score 0):

The text you want is next sibling of `.cit-series-title`. You can select that element and use javascript [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to getting next sibling text of it.

```js
var text = $(".cit-title > .cit-series-title")[0].nextSibling.textContent;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="cit-title">
    <span class="cit-series-title">Original article
        <span class="cit-sep cit-sep-after-article-series-title">:</span>
    </span>Pregnancy outcomes in patients with pulmonary arterial hypertension associated with congenital heart disease 
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first get the content of the entire `cit-title` element...

```
var wholeElementText = $('.cit-title').text();
```

...then get only the title text...

```
var titleText = $('.cit-title .cit-series-title').text();
```

...and *then* remove the `titleText` from the `wholeElementText`

```
var justThePartYouWant = wholeElementText.replace(titleText, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

select data from `span.cit-title` and store it to variable `A` and then select data from `span.cit-series-title` and store it to variable `B`

then do like `A.replace(B, '');` it will work

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert($(".cit-title").clone()    
           .children() 
           .remove()   
           .end()      
          .text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="cit-title">
    <span class="cit-series-title">Original article
        <span class="cit-sep cit-sep-after-article-series-title">:</span>
    </span>Pregnancy outcomes in patients with pulmonary arterial hypertension associated with congenital heart disease 
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the div in a temporary variable in order to remove the unwanted elements and get the text.

```
var div = $(".cit-title").clone();
div.find("span").first().remove();
div.text();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the better solution is to wrap the other text in another span like this:

```html
<span class="cit-title">
    <span class="cit-series-title">Original article<span class="cit-sep cit-sep-after-article-series-title">:</span> </span><span class="cit-series-description">Pregnancy outcomes in patients with pulmonary arterial hypertension associated with congenital heart disease</span> </span>
```

And then you get the inner text from `.cit-series-description` instead form the container.

Cheers