# is there any ways to put multiple textContent with same css values into a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, variables

I'm trying to find a way to put multiple text values that i extract from elements that has the same CSS and put them into a array in javascript. 
but i keep failing. i googled about it but couldn't find an answer for my problem.

anyone can tell what i did wrong and point out please?

here is the HTML part.

```
<div>
    James
   <div>English : <span class="jtest">80</span> </div>
   <div>Japanese : <span class="jtest">60</span> </div>
   <div>Science : <span class="jtest">78</span> </div>
   <div>Art : <span class="jtest">85</span> </div>
   <div>Philosophy : <span class="jtest">45</span> </div>
   <div>Physical tranning : <span class="jtest">65</span> </div>
</div>
<br><Br>
 <div>
    Von
   <div>English : <span class="vtest">80</span> </div>
   <div>Japanese : <span class="vtest">85</span> </div>
   <div>Science : <span class="vtest">67</span> </div>
   <div>Art : <span class="vtest">64</span> </div>
   <div>Philosophy : <span class="vtest">97</span> </div>
   <div>Physical tranning : <span class="vtest">25</span> </div>
</div>
<br><Br>
 <div>
    Crack
   <div>English : <span class="ctest">80</span> </div>
   <div>Japanese : <span class="ctest">88</span> </div>
   <div>Science : <span class="ctest">40</span> </div>
   <div>Art : <span class="ctest">70</span> </div>
   <div>Philosophy : <span class="ctest">80</span> </div>
   <div>Physical tranning : <span class="ctest">69</span> </div>
</div>
```

and here is javascript part.

```
<script>
var james = [''];
    james.push(document.getElementsByClassName("jtest"));
var Von = document.getElementsByClassName("vtest");
var Crack = document.getElementsByClassName("ctest");


console.log(james);
</script>
```

i want to put textContents of elements that has jtest class and put those values into a james variable like james ['80' , '60', '78', '85', '45', '65'];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get text node of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/get-text-node-of-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

```js
james = [];
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("jtest")).map(function(x){ james.push(x.textContent)});

console.log(james);
```

```html
<div>
    James
   <div>English : <span class="jtest">80</span> </div>
   <div>Japanese : <span class="jtest">60</span> </div>
   <div>Science : <span class="jtest">78</span> </div>
   <div>Art : <span class="jtest">85</span> </div>
   <div>Philosophy : <span class="jtest">45</span> </div>
   <div>Physical tranning : <span class="jtest">65</span> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a [node list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which does not have an `innerHTML` property. How is your code supposed to work?

Comment: my bad,i fixed it

Comment: Well, would be great if it returned an array, but unfortunately, it doesn't. It returns a node list, which for example doesn't have a `map` method.

Comment: @PeterMader `console.log(james.map); //function map() { [native code] }`

Comment: Of course, `james` is an array which you fill using the for loop. But the return value of `document.getElementsByClassName` is not an array. It's a node list.

Comment: @PeterMader `Array.from().map()`

Answer (score 0):

Array declaration should be like **`arrayName = [];`**, if you initialize the array while declaring like this `['']` it means `arrayName[0] = ''` and then whatever data you will push into array, it starts stores from index 1 as 0th index already has a `blank` value.

And you can fetch all the data of a `div` with property **`textContent`**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
  var james = [];
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("jtest");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    james.push(elements[i].textContent);
  }
  var Von = document.getElementsByClassName("vtest");
  var Crack = document.getElementsByClassName("ctest");


  console.log(james);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  James
  <div>English : <span class="jtest">80</span> </div>
  <div>Japanese : <span class="jtest">60</span> </div>
  <div>Science : <span class="jtest">78</span> </div>
  <div>Art : <span class="jtest">85</span> </div>
  <div>Philosophy : <span class="jtest">45</span> </div>
  <div>Physical tranning : <span class="jtest">65</span> </div>
</div>
<br>
<Br>
<div>
  Von
  <div>English : <span class="vtest">80</span> </div>
  <div>Japanese : <span class="vtest">85</span> </div>
  <div>Science : <span class="vtest">67</span> </div>
  <div>Art : <span class="vtest">64</span> </div>
  <div>Philosophy : <span class="vtest">97</span> </div>
  <div>Physical tranning : <span class="vtest">25</span> </div>
</div>
<br>
<Br>
<div>
  Crack
  <div>English : <span class="ctest">80</span> </div>
  <div>Japanese : <span class="ctest">88</span> </div>
  <div>Science : <span class="ctest">40</span> </div>
  <div>Art : <span class="ctest">70</span> </div>
  <div>Philosophy : <span class="ctest">80</span> </div>
  <div>Physical tranning : <span class="ctest">69</span> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Pawan !

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelector` to select all common `classes` i.e. (.jtest) then using `for loop` push each values to `james` array,

```js
var james = [];
var jtest = document.querySelectorAll(".jtest");
for (var i = 0; i <= jtest.length - 1; i++) {
  james.push(jtest[i].textContent);
}
console.log(james);
```

```html
<div>
  James
  <div>English : <span class="jtest">80</span> </div>
  <div>Japanese : <span class="jtest">60</span> </div>
  <div>Science : <span class="jtest">78</span> </div>
  <div>Art : <span class="jtest">85</span> </div>
  <div>Philosophy : <span class="jtest">45</span> </div>
  <div>Physical tranning : <span class="jtest">65</span> </div>
</div>
<br>
<Br>
<div>
  Von
  <div>English : <span class="vtest">80</span> </div>
  <div>Japanese : <span class="vtest">85</span> </div>
  <div>Science : <span class="vtest">67</span> </div>
  <div>Art : <span class="vtest">64</span> </div>
  <div>Philosophy : <span class="vtest">97</span> </div>
  <div>Physical tranning : <span class="vtest">25</span> </div>
</div>
<br>
<Br>
<div>
  Crack
  <div>English : <span class="ctest">80</span> </div>
  <div>Japanese : <span class="ctest">88</span> </div>
  <div>Science : <span class="ctest">40</span> </div>
  <div>Art : <span class="ctest">70</span> </div>
  <div>Philosophy : <span class="ctest">80</span> </div>
  <div>Physical tranning : <span class="ctest">69</span> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much frnt !