# Convert DOM childs to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```js
var allmenus = $('.dragger-menu').map(function() {
  var li = {};
  $(this).children('li').each(function() {
    switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
      case "page":
        li.page = {
          id: $(this).data("menu-id")
        };
        break;
      case "external-link":
        li["external-link"] = {
          title: $(this).text().trim(),
          url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
          icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
        }
        break;
      case "dropdown":
        li.dropdown = {};
        li.dropdown.title = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
          return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
        }).text().trim();
        li.dropdown.data = $(this).children("ol").map(function() {
          var data = {};
          $(this).children("li").each(function() {
            switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
              case "page":
                data.page = {
                  id: $(this).data("menu-id")
                };
                break;
              case "external-link":
                data["external-link"] = {
                  title: $(this).text().trim(),
                  url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
                  icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
                }
                break;
            }
          });
          return data;
        }).get();
        break;
    }
  });
  return li;
}).get();

var obj = {
  menu: allmenus
};
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
console.log(jsondata);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="dragger-menu">
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="24">Online Register</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="26">Secondly Page</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="dropdown">
      <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i> Dropdown Menu 
      <ol class="">
         <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="25">Contact Us</li>
         <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="external-link" data-menu-link="https://twitter.com/your-page"><i class="fa fa-Twitter"></i> Twitter</li>
         <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="external-link" data-menu-link="https://facebook.com/your-page"><i class="fa fa-Facebook"></i> Facebook</li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
<ol class="dragger-menu">
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="28">Ahmet Deneme</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="21">Secondly Page</li>
</ol>
```

The above javascript code does not pass the same type element to json. Example: If you are run the code, you see only page 26, not 24. This code only get last elem in same elem. I want the all elements in json data. What should i do in javascript code ? Sorry for my bad englısh . Thanks for all.

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: there: http://jsfiddle.net/ygbfn0xv/

Comment: That's another remote site. Post your code in the question.

Comment: I did man. sorry for my short description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't build JSON by concatenating strings. Create an object and then use `JSON.stringify`.

And use jQuery's `.each()` and `.map()` methods to loop through the DOM, rather than `for` loops.

```js
var allmenus = $('.dragger-menu').map(function() {
  var li = {};
  $(this).children('li').each(function() {
    switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
      case "page":
        li.page = {
          id: $(this).data("menu-id")
        };
        break;
      case "external-link":
        li["external-link"] = {
          title: $(this).text().trim(),
          url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
          icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
        }
        break;
      case "dropdown":
        li.dropdown = {};
        li.dropdown.title = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
          return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
        }).text().trim();
        li.dropdown.data = $(this).children("ol").map(function() {
          var data = {};
          $(this).children("li").each(function() {
            switch ($(this).data("menu")) {
              case "page":
                data.page = {
                  id: $(this).data("menu-id")
                };
                break;
              case "external-link":
                data["external-link"] = {
                  title: $(this).text().trim(),
                  url: $(this).data("menu-link"),
                  icon: $(this).children("i").attr("class")
                }
                break;
            }
          });
          return data;
        }).get();
        break;
    }
  });
  return li;
}).get();

var obj = {
  menu: allmenus
};
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
console.log(jsondata);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="dragger-menu">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="24">Online Register</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="external-link" data-menu-link="https://facebook.com/your-page"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i> Dropdown Menu
    <ol class="">
      <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="25">Contact Us</li>
      <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="external-link" data-menu-link="https://twitter.com/your-page"><i class="fa fa-Twitter"></i> Twitter</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
<ol class="dragger-menu">
  <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="28">Ahmet Deneme</li>
</ol>
```

The code to get the title of the dropdown came from [How to get the text node of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/how-to-get-the-text-node-of-an-element). It would be easier if you put that text inside a `<span>` so you can write a selector for it.

Comment: What do you mean? I have page 25 and page 28, that's all the elements.

Comment: I should have used `.children()`, it was selecting `li` nested further down in the HTML.

Comment: You commented out the `dropdown` part of your code, so I didn't put it in my answer. But you should get the general idea and be able to add that yourself. It's similar to this.

Comment: I don't know how make it for dropdown. Should I use nested function ?

Comment: No, just add a loop like `$(this).children("ol").children("li").each()` to create the `data:` property.

Comment: Just like the way I processed the `li` in `.dragger-menu`.

Comment: Do you really need everything done for you? You need to learn to generalize, you can't expect to find the exact code you need.

Comment: The code for processing the dropdown menu items is basically the same as the `dragger-menu` items. You might want to pull that out into a separate function to avoid repeating it. That will be especially useful if you allow multiple levels of nesting, since it can recurse as many times as necessary.

Comment: I get duplicate key error now. dublicate key "page". Should I put a number on the top of the keys after the menu? How can i do this?

Comment: That's a database error, what does it have to do with this HTML? I don't know what you mean by a number on top of the keys. The page IDs seem to be unique, one is id 24, another is ID 25, the last is ID 28. If these are duplicating something that's already in the database, you should probably fix that.

Comment: must be: "0": { "page": {  "id": {}    }    }, ... I want to count 0,1,2 before the key

Comment: <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="24">Online Register</li><li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="26">Page another</li>  When two pages, it doesn't read it all.

Comment: Where is `"0":` in the desired result in the question?

Comment: Please update the question. The sample input never has multiple pages inside the same `<ol>`. And it doesn't say the result must begin with `"0":`. I can only answer the question you ask, not the question you meant to ask.

Comment: You left out the expected result that goes with the new HTML.

Comment: You also got rid of your original, broken code. Readers of the question need to see what I was correcting, otherwise the answer makes less sense. Remember, this is a teaching tool for all users of the site, not just a way to get someone to write code for you personally.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I want to translate DOM elements into a JSON object.

The following function translates DOM elements into a JSON object:

```js
function DOM2JSON(elements) {
    var attributeToObj = attr => ({[attr.name]: attr.value});
    var attributeArrToObj = attrArr => 
        Object.assign({}, ...attrArr.map(attributeToObj));
    var elementToObj = el => ({
        tagName: el.tagName, 
        attributes: attributeArrToObj([...el.attributes]), 
        children: [...el.children].map(elementToObj) /* recursion here */
    });
    var obj = elements.map(elementToObj);
    return JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 2);
}

var json = DOM2JSON(Array.from(document.body.children));

console.log(json);
alert(json);
```

```html
<ol class="dragger-menu">
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="24">Online Register</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="external-link" data-menu-link="https://facebook.com/your-page"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="dropdown">
      <i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i> Dropdown Menu 
      <ol class="">
         <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="25">Contact Us</li>
         <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="external-link" data-menu-link="https://twitter.com/your-page"><i class="fa fa-Twitter"></i> Twitter</li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
<ol class="dragger-menu">
   <li class="list-group-item" data-menu="page" data-menu-id="28">Ahmet Deneme</li>
</ol>
```

You may complain that my solution works without JQuery.

In that case, add a single line `$("#nothing").hide();`.

Now it works and it uses JQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The comments about jQuery don't really add anything to this answer.

Comment: @Nick: I agree. OP wants it though.

Comment: @YavuzSelimÖzmen: I answered your question. Please, respond.

Comment: @YavuzSelimÖzmen: Not only you didn’t respond, you also [changed the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts) from one that I answered to one that I didn’t. Sneaky!