# Which interface type should I choose the in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
    let mdNode = document.querySelector('#test')

    let targetNode: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>Array.from(mdNode.childNodes).find(childNode => {
      if (childNode.nodeType === 1) {
        return childNode.innerHTML.indexOf('aaaa') !== -1
      }
    })
```

It tips `error TS2339: Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type 'ChildNode'`.

The `nodeType === 3` dose haven't innerHTML property, but the `nodeType ===1` have the innerHTML. What should I change to fix this error.

Comment: I use some hack way to avoid it. That is change to `childNode['innerHTML']`. But are there some elegant way to figure out that?

Comment: Why do you have to write this at all? What is it you are trying to accomplish? There might be a "pure"/native angular way to solve the same problem. Please share the component and template code along with a description of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Igor I try to get the node which include target string. [Some similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/how-to-get-the-text-node-of-an-element)