# How to get only TEXT_NODE with kuchiki

Tags: rust, kuchiki

I have this example HTML which I want to parse with [kuchiki](https://crates.io/crates/kuchiki):

```html
<a href="https://example.com"><em>@</em>Bananowy</a>
```

I want only `Bananowy` without `@`.

A similar question for JavaScript: [How to get the text node of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/how-to-get-the-text-node-of-an-element/6520267#6520267)

Comment: What is kuchiki? Can you please expand your question a little bit? E.g. some code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's start with how a parser will parse:

```html
    <a href="https://example.com"><em>@</em>Bananowy</a>
```

Into a tree. See image below:

[image]

Now if you try to do the obvious thing and call `anchor.text_contents()` you're going to get all text contents of all the text nodes descendants of the anchor tag (`<a>`). This is how text_contents behave according to CSS definition.

However, you want to just get the `"Bananowy"` you have few ways to do it:

```rust
extern crate kuchiki;

use kuchiki::traits::*;

fn main() {
    let html = r"<a href='https://example.com'><em>@</em>Bananowy</a>";

    let document = kuchiki::parse_html().one(html);

    let selector = "a";
    let anchor = document.select_first(selector).unwrap();
    // Quick and dirty hack
    let last_child = anchor.as_node().last_child().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", last_child.into_text_ref().unwrap());

    // Iterating solution
    for children in anchor.as_node().children() {
        if let Some(a) = children.as_text() {
            println!("{:?}", a);
        }
    }

    // Iterating solution - Using `text_nodes()` iterators
    anchor.as_node().children().text_nodes().for_each(|e| {
        println!("{:?}", e);
    });

    // text1 and text2 are examples how to get `String`
    let text1 = match anchor.as_node().children().text_nodes().last() {
        Some(x) => x.as_node().text_contents(),
        None => String::from(""),
    };

    let text2 = match anchor.as_node().children().text_nodes().last() {
        Some(x) => x.borrow().clone(),
        None => String::from(""),
    };
}
```

First way is the brittle, hackish way. All you need to realize is that `"Bananowy"` is the [last_child](https://docs.rs/kuchiki/0.7.3/kuchiki/struct.Node.html#method.last_child) of your anchor tag, and fetch it accordingly `anchor.as_node().last_child().unwrap().into_text_ref().unwrap()`.

The second solution is to iterate over anchor tag's children (i.e. `[Tag(em), TextNode("Bananowy")]`) and select only text nodes using ([`as_text()`](https://docs.rs/kuchiki/0.7.3/kuchiki/struct.Node.html#method.as_text) method). We do this with method `as_text()` that returns `None` for all `Nodes` that aren't `TextNode`. This is way less fragile than the first solution which won't work if e.g. you had `<a><em>@</em>Banan<i>!</i>owy</a>`.

EDIT:

## PREFERED Solution

After looking around for a bit I found a much better solution to your problem. It's called [TextNodes iterator](https://docs.rs/kuchiki/0.7.3/kuchiki/iter/struct.TextNodes.html).

With that in mind just write `anchor.as_node().children().text_nodes().<<ITERATOR CODE GOES HERE>>;` and then map or manipulate the entries as you see fit.

Why is this solution better? It's more succinct, it uses the good old fashioned `Iterator` so it's very similar to the answer in JS you gave above.

Comment: I have found this comment how to navigate documentation: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/af4ns6/how_to_work_with_refcell/