# How to get information in a nested div?

Tags: javascript, dom

This is my html:

```
    <div id="border1">parents nodes text
        <div id="border2">the target node
            <div id="border3">the main nodes child node</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to save first div output which is **parents nodes text** . when i use
`let big = document.getElementById("border1").innerText`

it will give me all texts in all of divs!

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You are trying to get the first text node, does this answer your question? [How to get the text node of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/how-to-get-the-text-node-of-an-element)

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```js
const mainElId = "border1";
const mainEl = document.getElementById(mainElId);
let data = {};
mainEl.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(n => {
  data[n.getAttribute('id')] = n.innerText;
  n.remove();
}
);
data[mainElId] = mainEl.innerText;
console.log(data);
```

```html
<div id="border1">parents nodes text
        <div id="border2">the target node
            <div id="border3">the main nodes child node</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i want to save each div information at the same time, this will remove every div except the first one!