# How can I get only the content of text nodes (not nested tags) from an HTML tag element in JS?

Tags: javascript, textnode

Suppose I have

```
<div id="mydiv">
     <span>foo</span>
     <span>bar</span>
     bob
</div>
```

Is there a JavaScript function/property which will return "bob"?

I tried `document.getElementById('mydiv').textContent` but that gives "foobarbob", as does `innerText`.  I could parse the return of `innerHTML` by stripping out any tags and their contents, but I'm guessing there's a better way?

Thank you

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/how-to-get-the-text-node-of-an-element what you are looking for?

Comment: @prettyInPink - That's jQuery-specific. But there *has* to be one that isn't somewhere....

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have stipulated that I don't want a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

`bob` is in a `Text` node in the div. You can't select a [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) node directly, but you can access it via the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) on its parent (or `nextSibling` on the `span` in front of it, etc.):

```js
const div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
console.log("`nodeValue` of each text node in the div:");
for (const child of div.childNodes) {
    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        console.log(child.nodeValue);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
     <span>foo</span>
     <span>bar</span>
     bob
</div>
```

Note how you see multiple log lines, not just one for `bob`, and that `bob` has whitespace around it. In your div, there are **three** `Text` nodes:

- The one with the whitespace between the beginning of the `div` and the first `span`.
- The one with the whitespace between the two `span`s.
- The one at the end with all of the text (including whitespace) between the end of the second `span` and the end of the `div`.

So as Felix Kling pointed out in a comment *(now deleted)*, if you don't want that whitespace, you may need to trim it off (`nodeValue.trim()`) and/or ignore nodes that only have whitespace in them.

You could also use the `textContent` property on the div, which will give you the text of all of its child **and** descendant `Text` nodes (so that includes `foo` and `bar`, not just `bob`):

```js
const div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
console.log("`textContent`:", div.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
     <span>foo</span>
     <span>bar</span>
     bob
</div>
```

Comment: Whoops, shouldn't have deleted my comment until I read the whole update :D

Comment: @FelixKling - Heh, it's fine. People know comments disappear. :D

Comment: Thanks.  You're right on the whitespace specifics, but in fact in my ACTUAL use case there is no whitespace between the tags - I always avoid it when possible!