# How to remove punctuation without changing HTML tags in a JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a Chrome extension that strips the punctuation from a page, but my code also affects all the HTML tags of the page as well. The ID, the style, and even the SVG paths are affected by the punctuation change.

```
function removePunctuation(text) {
    text = text.replace(/[\.#!£$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()@\+\?\[\]\+]/g, ' ').replace(/  +/g, ' ')
    return text
}

let textTags = document.querySelectorAll('p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, li, td, caption, span, a, div');
for (let i = 0, l = textTags.length; i < l; i++) {
    textTags[i].innerHTML = removePunctuation(textTags[i].innerHTML)
}
```

1. To get all of the text from a page, I'm using `document.querySelectorAll`.
2. To take away all the punctuation, except angle brackets, from the innerHTML of the element, I loop through each element and use the regex above with the `String.prototype.replace()` method
3. I set the result back onto the page.

I unsuccessfully tried to save the position of each tag, take it out and add it back in once the punctuation is removed. It always excludes the parameters or misses out on some tags.

I also tried to find a regex that would exclude HTML tags from the removal of punctuation but looking at regex as a whole, I'm not sure if that's even possible!

Comment: I believe you will find parsing HTML to be a significant challenge with regex FWIW

Comment: I don't think, the problem is particularly with the RegExp itself. Of course, you _could_ explicitly exclude your tags from the RegExp, but wouldn't it be better to only replace the content of [`Text` nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the textNodes in the document. Then update their `nodeValue`.

Taking some code from [How to get the text node of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73693244/128165) to extract all textNodes and
you can then apply your code to only these

```js
const deepNonEmptyTextNodes = el => [...el.childNodes].flatMap(e =>
  e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && e.textContent.trim() ?
  e : deepNonEmptyTextNodes(e)
);

function removePunctuation(text) {
  return text.replace(/[\.#!£$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()@\+\?\[\]\+]/g, ' ').replace(/  +/g, ' ');
}

let textTags = [...document.querySelectorAll('p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, li, td, caption, span, a, div')];

textTags.forEach(tagNode => {
  const textNodes = deepNonEmptyTextNodes(tagNode);
  textNodes.forEach(node => node.nodeValue = removePunctuation(node.nodeValue))
})
```

```html
<p>clean up the following !£$%^& chars</p>
<strong>stay as $%^&* you are</strong>
<div>clean these !£$%^&[]@ also</div>
```

---

Keep in mind, though, that this code will modify text nodes inside tags you do not want, if they are nested inside tags you do want. So, if a `strong` tag is inside a `div` it will be cleaned up too.

In the same answer i linked to, you will find other methods that only return the immediate child text nodes of an element, if that is what you want.

Comment: This looks like the best way to go - I'll test it out when I next can and if I can get it working the green tick is yours!

Comment: Just tested it out and works a charm - thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just focus the regular text tag?

Like just look in the `<p>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>` …, `<span>`, `<em>`, `<strong>`, `<textarea>`, etc.

Comment: The only two problems with that are often website put text inside divs, and that other tags are often nested within text tags.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).