# How to properly use a counting loop in Javascript +HTML

Tags: javascript, html, loops, html5-history

In Javascript, I am trying to create a counting loop that adds one to a number. I am new to counting loops in the context of Javascript, but i tried my best and found something from the Internet.

This is my code:

```
var number = document.getElementById("mainText")

for (let i = number; i < 101; i++) {
  number += 1;
}
```

I am also going to add the HTML for context.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Loading....</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./starting.css">
</head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1f2023aaf1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
<i id="fa" class="fa fa-spinner fa-10x"></i>"></i><br>
<p id="mainText">0</p>
<p class="idk">%</p>            
</body>
</html>
```

The problem, however, is that when I run it, it still remains at 0(%). Whatever am I doing wrong. Hope this code helps.

Brussels is the capital of Belgium by the way.

Comment: you return an element. You have to use `textContent` to retrieve the number. However, it is a bad way to start in the first place. rather let the loop update it directly instead of reading it out every increment.

Comment: Wrong duplicate. It should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520192/how-to-get-the-text-node-of-an-element The answer without jQuery is https://stackoverflow.com/a/34700627/16540390

Comment: while this is a better duplicate, it shouldnt be solved as duplicate but by its wrong approach

Comment: Your HTML is STILL invalid. Fix it please, read the comments in your other question

Comment: You need to set the text of the element. Appending a numerical value to the Element object will not do that. See the duplicates for more information on how to get/set the text of elements. However, you should note that your output will instantly show `101` - assuming your intention is for the count to be incremental.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan just 100 as the condition is `< 101`. But right there is missing context to the task

Comment: @tacoshy 100 is the last iteration, but it then adds another 1 to it :)

Comment: my bad suggesting that something will be updated at this point (which is not)..

Comment: @tacoshy @jabaa @RoryMcCrossan I have updated this code with:
```
var number = $(".mainText").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).text();

for (let i = number; i < 101; i++) {
  number += 1;
}
```
But still it doesn't work.

Comment: Update the QUESTION instead of pasting code in a comment

Comment: The code you pasted is really really overkill. You want `var number = +document.getElementById("mainText").textContent;` which will get the text and convert it to a number. But your loop will run so fast you will just see 101 immediately. You likely want `let tId = setInterval(function() { if (number >= 101) clearInterval(tId); else number++;},1000);` which will count up every second

Comment: I've added a link to an answer without jQuery. Do you load jQuery? I don't see it in your code. You can't use it without loading it before.