# jQuery getting a text but no html

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the contents of an element WITHOUT its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172166/getting-the-contents-of-an-element-without-its-children)

How can I get `foobar` out of the following HTML with jquery/javascript, without using regular expressions?

```
<div id="somediv">
foobar
<span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```
$("#somediv").text();
```

Or, if the `span` has content which you want to ignore, use:

```
$("#somediv").contents().first().text();
```

Comment: the second one is great :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the text from the first child node, use

```
$("#somediv").contents().eq(0).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var text = document.getElementById("somediv").getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: that would return both the text and the span tag or whatever else is inside

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$('#somediv').text().trim();
```

The trim will get rid of the extra whitespace from the carriage returns and leave you with just foobar.