# how can i get the string of list by jquery selector or filter

Tags: jquery, list, filter, nested, selector

here is my html code

```
<ul id='mylist'>
<li><a href='/datas/serverside.html'>Server side</a>
    <ul>
    <li>JSP</li>
    <li>PHP</li>
    <li>ASP</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Database
    <ul>
    <li>ORACLE</li>
    <li>MySQL</li>
    <li>Ms-SQL</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

how can I get only this html or string `"<a href='/datas/serverside.html'>Server side</a>"` and "Database"  exclusive of sub ul list itmems?

Comment: are you able to add an id or class to the ul or li?

Comment: sorry, i miss the outer ul's id

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the contents of an element WITHOUT its children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172166/getting-the-contents-of-an-element-without-its-children)