# How to get the value of a span that contains another span with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have one `<span>` tag inside another one.

```
<span id="count">255<span>words</span></span>
```

and I would like to get only the value of the first `<span>` tag, the value `255`.

What I have tried:

```
var words = document.getElementById('count'); //Gets the <span>

alert(words.value); //undefined --> does not exist for <span> tag
alert(words.innerHTML); //255<span>words</span>
alert(words.innerText); //255words
alert(words.textContent); //255words
```

And I know I can do:

```
var storedWords = words.innerText;
storedWords = storedWords.replace('words','');
alert(storedWords); //255
```

but I would like to do it directly.

Is it possible to retrieve only the value of the first span?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the contents of an element WITHOUT its children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172166/getting-the-contents-of-an-element-without-its-children)

Comment: use like `$('#count').find('span').html()`

Comment: Another reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6520192/5812121

Comment: @Dharmeshpatel I am not using JQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get the SPAN element, then select it's first child(which is text node) and then get it's value

```
document.getElementById('count').firstChild.nodeValue
```

**NOTE:** This will return you text and if you want int in integer then you need to parse it using parseInt function with decimal base(base 10).

```
parseInt(document.getElementById('count').firstChild.nodeValue, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Kind of variant

```js
var allNodes = document.getElementById('count').childNodes;
var text="";
for( var i in allNodes ){
   if( allNodes[i].nodeType == 3 ){
     text += " "+allNodes[i].wholeText;
   }
}

console.log( text );
```

```html
<span id="count">255<span>words</span><div>text</div>text</span>
```

**Updated** snippet for first level text, even if there other elements

Comment: Better than the accepted solution, as it is not limited to the first text fragment only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get all text that is not wrapped in child elements:

```js
function getText(node) {
    // Take clone of the node
    var node = node.cloneNode(true);
    // remove child elements from it, not text nodes
    for (child of node.childNodes){
        if (child.nodeType !== 3) node.removeChild(child);
    }
    return node.textContent;
}

console.log (getText(document.querySelector('span#count')));
```

```html
<span id="count">255 <span>words</span> or 127</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd like to offer a couple of further options:

```
function getChildTextOf (n) {
  // retrieving the childNodes of the passed-in node (n)
  // and converting those nodes into an Array
  let text = Array.from( n.childNodes )
    // filtering that Array to retain only those nodes
    // whose nodeType is equal to 3 (and so are textNodes)
    .filter( n => n.nodeType === 3 )
    // returning a new Array composed of the nodeValue
    // (the text) of those nodes:
    .map(n => n.nodeValue);

  // if we have a truthy value stored in the text variable,
  // and that that text variable (an Array) is of length
  // 1 we return the first element of the Array (a String),
  // otherwise we return the whole Array:
  return text && text.length === 1 ? text.shift() : text;
}

console.log(getChildTextOf(document.getElementById('count')));
```

```js
function getChildTextOf(n) {
  let text = Array.from(n.childNodes).filter(n => n.nodeType === 3).map(n => n.nodeValue);

  return text && text.length === 1 ? text.shift() : text;
}

console.log(getChildTextOf(document.getElementById('count')));
```

```html
<span id="count">255<span>words</span></span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uu3uw26v/).

And:

```
function getChildTextOf (n) {

  // cloning the passed-in node (n), along
  // with its own children:
  let clone = n.cloneNode(true);

  // retrieving the children (child-elements) of the
  // cloned-node, converting that collection into an
  // Array, to use Array methods:
  Array.from( clone.children )

    // iterating over that Array of element-children
    // removing each child from its parent (the clone)
    .forEach(child => clone.removeChild(child));

  // normalising the clone, which combines all text-nodes
  // into one, removing any/all empty nodes:
  clone.normalize();

  // returning the textContent of that clone:
  return clone.textContent;
}

console.log(getChildTextOf(document.getElementById('count')));
```

```js
function getChildTextOf(n) {
  let clone = n.cloneNode(true);
  Array.from(clone.children).forEach(child => clone.removeChild(child));
  clone.normalize();
  return clone.textContent;
}

console.log(getChildTextOf(document.getElementById('count')));
```

```html
<span id="count">255<span>words</span></span>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uu3uw26v/1/).

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Node.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
- [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue).
- [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).
- [`Node.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize).
- [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).
- [`Node.textContent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Answer (score -1):

you can use this too
$('#count').contents()[0]

Comment: Ah. Sorry for that, Did not notice.